# View only Document Libraries in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, document-library

We've migrated from Sharepoint 2003.  In Sharepoint 2003, there were a link in on the left hand side, called Documents.  When you click this link, it list all document libraries in the site.  How do you view only your document libraries in your Sharepoint 2013 site?  I'm aware of the 'Site Contents' link, but this shows everything - lists, apps and libraries - I only want to view Libraries.

Answer (score 3):

For the requirement of showing a list of document libraries, at this time, there isn't any straightforward way to achieve the goal.

1. There's a predefined "Links list" you could use but you'd have to manually add the library urls as items in the List and Display the link to that list in the Naviagtion panel.
2. Another workaround, you can manually add all of these document libraries on the left quick launch of the site.

Anyway, I realize that the workarounds above may seem to be complicated and not flexible.

[Source](http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/158/t/190628.aspx)

Comment: Thanks!  Will the same link work for 2013?

Comment: Now I dont have a SP 2013 environment to test it, could you please test it and let us know.

Comment: Nope - it gives me same result as when I click on Site contents. (lists and apps included)

Comment: I have edited with new approaches, kindly try it and let us know.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions Karthik.  I assume both options is not dynamically?  Therefore I would need to keep the list or the links on left manually updated as well.  Will speak to my client, and give them the options.  Thanks again for your solutions.